# Salting Technique to tackle Skew in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand `Salting` techniques to tackle `Skew` in Spark SQL. I have done some reading online and I have come up with a very rudimentary implementation of the same in Spark SQL API.

Let's assume that `table1` is Skewed on `cid=1`:

Table 1:

```
cid | item
---------
1   | light
1   | cookie
1   | ketchup
1   | bottle
2   | dish
3   | cup
```

As shown above, `cid=1` occurs more than other keys.

Table 2:

```
cid | vehicle
---------
1   | taxi
1   | truck
2   | cycle
3   | plane
```

Now my code looks like the following:

```
create temporary view table1_salt as
select
cid, item, concat(cid, '-', floor(rand() * 19)) as salted_key
from table1;

create temporary view table2_salt as
select
cid, vehicle, explode(array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)) as salted_key
from table2;
```

Final Query:

```
select a.cid, a.item, b.name
from table1_salt a
inner join table2_salt b
on a.salted_key = concat(b.cid, '-', b.salted_key);
```

In the above example, I have used `20` salts/splits.

**Questions:**

- Is there any rule of thumb to choose optimal number for the splits to
  be used ? For e.g. if `table1` has `10 Million` records, how many bins/buckets should I use ? (In this simple test example I have used `20`).
- As shown above, when I am creating `Table2_salt`, I am hardcoding the
  the salts like (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`.... thru `19`). Is there a better
  way to implement the same functionality, but without the
  hardcoding and the clutter ? (What if I want to use `100` splits!)
- Since we are replicating the second table (`table2`) `N` number of times, doesn't it mean that it will degrade the Join performance ?

*Note: I need to use Spark 2.4 SQL API only.*

Also, kindly let me know if there are any advanced examples available on the net. Any help is appreciated.